# Redirect print in Python: val = print(arg) to output mixed iterable to file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterable

So lets say I have an incredibly nested iterable of lists/dictionaries.  I would like to print them to a file as easily as possible.  Why can't I just redirect print to a file?

`val = print(arg)` 
gets a SyntaxError.

Is there a way to access stdinput?

And why does print take forever with massive strings?  Bad programming on my side for outputting massive strings, but quick debugging--and isn't that leveraging the strength of an interactive prompt?

There's probably also an easier way than my gripe.  Has the hive-mind an answer?

Comment: Which version of Python?  2.x?  3.x?  For `print`, it happens to matter.

Comment: 2.x.  You're right, that's a good inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't typically use `print` for writing to a file (though you technically can). You would use a file object for this.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(repr(your_thingy))
```

If `print` is taking forever to display a massive string, it is likely that it's not exactly `print`'s fault, but the result of having to display all that to screen.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.

The problem I was having with my nested list/dict is I couldn't easily write it to a file, but could easily print it.  This is the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module of Python. Perhaps that's the perfect match in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how you're using `print` as function, [docs say that you can redirect to file](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) like this:

```
print(arg, file=open('fname', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python `3.*`, to redirect one `print` call to an open file object `destination`,

```
print(arg, file=destination)
```

In Python `2.*`, where `print` is a statement, the syntax is

```
print>>destination, arg
```

I imagine you're using `2.*` because in `3.*` assigning `print`'s result is not a syntax error (it's just useless, since that result is `None`, but allowed).  In `2.*` `print` is a **statement**, not a function, so the code snippet you give is indeed a syntax error.

I'm not sure what the assignment is supposed to mean.  If you want to redirect one or more `print` statements (or calls) to get the formatted result as an in-memory string, you can set `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` (or `cStringIO`) instance; but you specifically mention "to a file" so I'm really perplexed as to the intended meaning of that assignment.  Clarify pls?

Comment: You're right, I'm using 2.x.  

The issue is I need to output the result of parsing xml into data structures that are necessarily nested lists/dicts.  Writing them to files was difficult, but printing them worked.  Obviously it'd be better to write a validator, but this is a one-off thing that's a side project. 

The answer was the repr() function, which gets the string representation and allows me to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both examples with no success using python 2.7

To begin I created a file in C:\goat.text using notepad

Next I tried the following

**import sys**

**print>>"C:\goat.txt", "test"**
error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

**print("test", file=open('C:\goat.txt', 'w'))**

SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input '='", ('C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-tmp5165417708161227735.py', 3, 18, 'print("test", file=open(\'C:\\goat.txt\', \'w\')) \n'))

I've tried multiple variants annd can't solve this.